# Thumbnal images not aligningn horizontally

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"><br><br><img src="images\smartphone.png" class="img-circle" alt="" width="243" height="241" align="middle"><br><h4  style="color:#1E7145" align="center">Smart Phone</h4></div>   
    <div class="col-md-4"><br><br><img src="images\oldphone.png" class="img-circle" alt="" width="243" height="241" align="middle"><br><h4 style="color:#1E7145" align="center">Basic Phone</h4></div>  
    <div class="col-md-4"><br><br><img src="images\tab.png" class="img-circle" alt="" width="243" height="241" align="middle"><br><h4 style="color:#1E7145" align="center">Tablet</h4></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The thumbnail images are not aligned to the center.However the texts are aligned to center.The images are aligned to the left.Is there a solution?

Comment: Have you tried with `<div class="col-md-4 text-center"> ...` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following code using *flex*:

```
.imager div{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

}
```

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row imager">
        <div class="col-md-4"><br><br><img src="images\smartphone.png" class="img-circle" alt="" width="243" height="241" align="middle"><br><h4  style="color:#1E7145" align="center">Smart Phone</h4></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><br><br><img src="images\oldphone.png" class="img-circle" alt="" width="243" height="241" align="middle"><br><h4 style="color:#1E7145" align="center">Basic Phone</h4></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><br><br><img src="img-circle" class="img-circle" alt="" width="243" height="241" align="middle"><br><h4 style="color:#1E7145" align="center">Tablet</h4></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.col-md-4 {
 text-align:center;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4"><br><br><img src="images\smartphone.png" class="img-circle" alt="" width="243" height="241" align="middle"><br><h4  style="color:#1E7145" align="center">Smart Phone</h4></div>   
 <div class="col-md-4"><br><br><img src="images\oldphone.png" class="img-circle" alt="" width="243" height="241" align="middle"><br><h4 style="color:#1E7145" align="center">Basic Phone</h4></div>  
 <div class="col-md-4"><br><br><img src="images\tab.png" class="img-circle" alt="" width="243" height="241" align="middle"><br><h4 style="color:#1E7145" align="center">Tablet</h4></div>
</div>
</div>
```